# No mannaged connection when using jms

Tags: jms, wildfly

I am using wildfly jms queue... I'm using wildfly 9.0.2.Final

I make the producer like this :

```
@Inject
private JMSContext jmsContext;
private JMSProducer jmsProducer;    

@Resource(mappedName = "java:/jboss/exported/jms/queue/TosDownloadReport")
private Queue queueDownloadReport;      

public void downloadReport(String adminId, DownloadReportFilter filter){
    try {
        jmsProducer = jmsContext.createProducer();
        String requestParam = Json.getInstance().getObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(filter);
        LOG.info("requestParam {}", requestParam);
        String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");
        RoutingRequest request = new RoutingRequest();
        request.putProperty("id", id);
        request.putProperty("adminId", adminId);
        request.putProperty("parameterRequest", requestParam);

        QueueMsgDownloadReport message = new QueueMsgDownloadReport();
        message.setId(id);
        message.setAdminId(adminId);

        String jsonMsg = Json.getInstance().getObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(message);

        gatewayService.send(RESOURCE, METHOD, request);
        jmsProducer.send(queueDownloadReport, jsonMsg);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage(),e);
    }
}
```

But sometimes i get exception like this and i must restart wildfly

```
2017-05-05 11:08:20,004 ERROR [com.daksa.tos.infrastructure.api.TosTimer] (EJB default - 7) Could not create a session: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/JmsXA: javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException: Could not create a session: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/JmsXA
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000655: No managed connections available within configured blocking timeout (30000 [ms])
```

From what i read, i don't need to call jmsContext.close() if i'm using inject right?

Please tell me what i do wrong...Thx

Comment: As per http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jms20-1947669.html you don't have to worry about JMSContext if you are injecting it. However are you using java:/JmsXA i.e pooledconnection factory in your code ? How many simultaneously requests are coming on it ? You can increase `max-pool-size` of connection factory.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply...Yes, i'm using java:/JmsXA...I think the request will be about 1 every 10 seconds and i have 6 code like that...You mean pool size in this section "<strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>" ?

Comment: Now i try using mdb using old way like this connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(); and i add connection.close at the end of the code. The exception not show again, does the injecting jmsContext has a bug?

Comment: You mean pool size in this section "<strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" .....  No. pooled connection factory defines its own pool size. You can do read-resource using CLI command on  JmsXA.   Regarding connection close, need to check.